# Mapbox SDK for android doesn't install properly

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm new in programing and i want to create a map app, so I'm trying to install the Mapbox SDK in android studio (Kotlin), I've followed the installation guide step by step (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/), but it doesnt'n import and classes are not getting created, and I don't know what's wrong.

build gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.30"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build gradle (module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.maptest04"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

In main activity when i put the imports, the word mapbox appears in red, and also the words Mapview, Mapbox and Style appear in red in "class MainActivity"

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private var mapView: MapView? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->

            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {

            }     
      }
  }
```

And in the XML when i put this

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

everything appears in red saying that "the classes in the layout file were not found in the project or libraries"

Answer (score 0):

So did you configure the download token in **gradle.properties** in the gradle home directory. If you use Mac the file should locate at **/Users/you/.gradle/gradle.properties.** For windows it should be **C:\Users<you>. gradle\gradle.properties.**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I put the secret token in Gradle Scrips > gradle.properties that is inside android studio, but i think that I have to install Gradle i put the secrete token in the place that you said.

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently is the SDK version, for some reason the actual SDK doesn't run, so I did teh exact installation process with an older SDK version and worked just fine.